# Keeping an absolute positioned element's width dependent on its text content's preferred width

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm positioning elements containing only text inside another element using absolute positions (think Tooltips).

The width of the Tooltip element should be according to its text content with some maximum width - sometimes it's only a word, sometimes multiple lines.
I need to be able to set the left-aligned position of the tooltip element and move it outside of the containing box.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tooltip">Sed venenatis diam ligula, at sagittis arcu blandit in.</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Now, as soon as I move the Tooltip element towards the right edge of its container it shrinks to fit into that container.

Here's an interactive Fiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/meyertee/GKFXN/

Is there a pure CSS way to make the Tooltip element behave on the right side as it does on the left side - i.e. make itself as wide as the text would prefer to be?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is not possible without setting a min-width to it. Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890750/min-width-max-width-css-use-smallest-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS transform: translate(x, y) instead of left: x. http://jsfiddle.net/jYKrS/

```
$("#positionSlider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 150,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".tooltip").css("transform", "translate(" + ui.value + "%, 0)");
    }
});
```

You may have to add all the prefixed versions for better compatability.

```
transform: translate(x, y);
-webkit-transform: translate(x, y);
-moz-transform: translate(x, y);
-ms-transform: translate(x, y);
-o-transform: translate(x, y);
```

Comment: Nice, tested it on Chrome 29/FF 22/Safari 6 on OS X. I added a Fiddle with px rather than %: http://jsfiddle.net/meyertee/5vxHU/

Comment: There's one limitation to the solution - due to the way it works I guess: If the container is too small to begin with the problem returns: http://jsfiddle.net/meyertee/7FMUK/ Fortunately that's not a problem for me now..

Comment: @meyertee - at that point you'd have to use javascript/jquery to set a width on the tooltip DIV.

Comment: It should be noted that this script doesn't really answer the question: "Is there a pure CSS way [...]"

Comment: @AlejandroIván - Actually it does, while the example uses a JavaScript slider, you can trivially attach the provided CSS transform to a :target or :hover selector. The provided JavaScript is ONLY for easy demonstration purposes, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to clearly answer not knowing exactly how you want to use the tooltip.

If you wan't to move it to the right outside of the box, without the box going wild, you can use `right: -10px` instead of `left: ___px;`

An alternative would be to use `white-space: nowrap`. This way you could position using `left` but it would force you add the line-breaks manually (which I don't think is an option).

Finally, I think using jQuery you already know the answer. It could be something like this:

```
$.each(".tooltip", function() { // Or on display
    $(this).css("min-width", $(this).width());
});
```

Comment: I edited my question, clarifying that I need to set the left position and move it outside the box (as demonstrated in the Fiddle).. thank you still. Unfortunately nowrap is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the tooltip min-width to it's original width with jQuery?

I just added this to the javascript :

```
$('.tooltip').css('min-width',$('.tooltip').width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/meyertee/GKFXN/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting this in the tooltip CSS.

```
.tooltip {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

here is another version that uses a js if statement for basically the same results

http://jsfiddle.net/GKFXN/56/