# How to make div/table change their size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div which contains another 3 divs, and each of them has a table.
I want them to change their size depending on screen size.
The reason why I need it is because:
If page are opened on 1366x768 resolution then page footer are moved with it and as a result, I am getting scrollbar. Because one of the tables already has scrollbar by itself, another scrollbar seems ugly. On bigger resolution everything seems fine (except maybe tables looks smaller and there a big amount of empty space under them).

I read that it could be done with css help but will this kind of solution will work on a different browser? (IE and Chrome for example).

Comment: Try using % widths instead of fixed width in px

Comment: Refer Chris's answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890750/min-width-max-width-css-use-smallest-width

Answer (score 2):

Give `max-width` to your most outer `div` which contains other DIVs and then use `percentage %` for inner DIVs

Assuming you have a container `div` is `960px` wide if you have a col div in the container as `320px` wide then that would be `33.33%`

```
320*100/960 = 33.33%
```